# How can I show a waitcursor while waiting for a combobox to render?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a strange issue when binding a combobox in a WPF window.

I am loading a List object, to populate the combobox, through it's .ItemsSource, on Window Load, however, it does not populate.

At least, not until the arrow is clicked on.   Once the arrow is clicked on, the window freezes up, and after a minute or so, the 4000+ records are displayed in it.

Now, the list gets loaded, however, when I click on the combobox it takes awhile for it to render, so how can I show a waitcursor while it is rendering the list?

Here's the Xaml for it:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Name="tUser" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      DisplayMemberPath="UsersName" SelectedValuePath="UserID" SelectedValue="0"/>
```

And the code-behind is:

```vb
Private Sub CreateTask_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Using New WaitCursor
        _LA.Show()
        Me.tOrder.ItemsSource = GetOrderList()
        Me.tUser.ItemsSource = GetUserList()
        _LA.Hide()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetUserList() As List(Of UserTyping)
    Dim _Qry As New List(Of UserTyping)
    Using db As New DataAccess
        With db
            .QueryType = CmdType.InlineSQL
            .Query = "Select 0 As UserID, '-Select User-' As UsersName Union All Select userID As UserID, userFullName As UsersName From vwSelectUser"
            Using _Results = .GetResults()
                If _Results IsNot Nothing Then
                    If _Results IsNot Nothing Then
                        _Qry = (From row In _Results.Cast(Of DbDataRecord)()
                                    Select New UserTyping() With {
                                        .UserID = Common.IsNull(Of Long)(row, 0, 0),
                                        .UsersName = Common.IsNull(Of String)(row, 1, String.Empty)
                                        }).ToList()
                    Else
                        _Qry = New List(Of UserTyping)
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
        End With
    End Using
    Return _Qry
    _Qry.Clear()
End Function
Partial Public Class UserTyping
    Public Property UserID As Long
    Public Property UsersName As String
End Class
```

Comment: Simply Move the codes from "ComboBox Click" event to the "form load" event.The Code you provide here is for add items to the list not to the combobox.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this first,it's still gonna take a while to load your application unless you use multi-threding.

Comment: Please re-read the code I posted.  The combobox is populated by the function pulling the data, and there is nothing at all in the combobox click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but...

If you want to avoid waiting when you open the `ComboBox` for the first time when it has many items, you can set `ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen` to `True` and back to `False`.

Edit:
A little bit of research turned up [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henryh/archive/2007/06/15/loading-a-combobox-with-many-items-is-slow.aspx). Basically, your XAML will look like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

I was able to view a `ComboBox` with 40k numbers instantly.

Comment: What I am really looking to do, is simply have the 'WaitCursor', and _LA show until the combobox is completely populated.  In other words, I don't want the window to be available for actions until that combobox is completely loaded.  that way, there is no way time when clicking the combobox.

Comment: Any chance my edit eliminates that type of wait time altogether?

Comment: Sorry, I am too new at Xaml to know what you mean :)  I changed to it that:
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Name="tUser" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      DisplayMemberPath="UsersName" SelectedValuePath="UserID" SelectedValue="0">
                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ComboBox>

but it still does the same thing

Comment: Honestly, I'm not concerned about the wait time.  In fact, I would prefer it.

The issue at hand is the fact that the combobox does not appear to populate it's ItemSource until it is clicked, instead of on window load as specified in the codebehind

Comment: Well, the ComboBox should be populated right after you set ItemSource. The reason for the pause you experienced is because the layouts for its elements haven't been computed yet. What VirtualizingStackPanel does is only load the layouts for visible elements, so it's odd that it's not working for you.

Comment: I would have thought that too.  Yeah, even then stackpanel makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing loading with rendering.  In the example below the get is called by the Window_Loaded and NOT by the click on the CB. Once the Window first dislayed the cb object already has its data - the drop down is just not rendered in the default state.  Are far as getting the ComboBox to pre-render that just does not make sense as the default state of the combobox is just the single row.  Assign a SelectedIndex of 1 and you will see the value when the Widow is first displayed - evidence the combobox already has its data.

```
    public List<string> cbSource
    {
        get 
        {
            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                ss.Add("jim_" + i.ToString());
                ss.Add("mary_" + i.ToString());
                ss.Add("steve" + i.ToString());
            }
            return ss;
        }
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cb.ItemsSource = cbSource;
    }
```

Comment: When I add VirtualizingStackPanel to my test I got sub second rendering (and load).  +1 Timis0r.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with anyone here.  I realize, and know that the list is loaded into the combobox on load.  How can I display a waitcursor while it renders everything?

Comment: OK then you might change the question from "How, can I get it to completely load" as I would call bound to the data loaded.  My experience is that you have no/zero programmatic control over rendering.  Just as you cannot debug in the XAML.  Not saying I like  it but that appears to be the reality. The good news it that you should be able to fix rendering with virtualization.  You can display an hour glass from code behind but creating the collection is not what takes the time.  I would be happy just to be able to cancel rendering an object just as you can cancel a backgoundworker operation.